# In tablesorter, dropdown list is not updated after a filter is set from other columns

Tags: tablesorter

I just tried on the demo page: https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html

I filtered the data with:
Major: math
Calculus: 100

and after that only three records left that are all male students. But I still can choose female from the dropdown list for filtering Sex.

How can I update the dropdown list after I set some other filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to use the [`filter-onlyAvail` class name](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#classes) on the header.

After adding that class, the select in that column will only show available (visible) options for that specified column. If you look at [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html#default_select_with_only_available_options) at the "Discount" column. You'll see the options are limited as filters are applied to other columns.

Comment: That's fantastic. Cheers.